# Como enviar bytes a una impresora térmica (POS) Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, print

estoy haciendo un programa para abrir la caja conectada a la impresora térmica, pero tengo un problema y es que no sé enviar bytes a la impresora ni para abrir la caja, ni para cortar el papel, aunque sepa los bytes requeridos, lo único que encuentro es para java pero quisiera hacerlo en kotlin.

La impresora esta conectada mediante un usb al pc y a su vez la caja mediante un cable lan (si no me equivoco) a la impresora

> Abrir la caja: 27,112,48,55,121

Muchas gracias

Comment: Hola, debes tener una forma de comunicarte con el dispositivo. Debes aclarar cómo realizas la conexión con el mismo. De lo contrario tu pregunta es muy amplia. Saludos

Comment: Okey gracias. Ya lo he aclarado

Comment: Lo que llamas LAN, es en realidad una interfaz [RS-232](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-232) que permite comunicación serial con el equipo, mediante el uso de un cable que tiene uno o los dos extremos con conector [8P8C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_connector#8P8C). La impresora a su vez usa protocolo de comunicación en serie a través de Universal Serial Bus. Lo que debes hacer es crear o abrir una forma de comunicación usando el puerto de conexión de la impresora. Es mucho el camino a recorrer desde lo que tienes hasta lo que necesitas. Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias. Buscare información al respeto. Aun asi si alguien puede y quiere publicar la respuesta para ahorrarmelo a mi y a quien lo busque en futuro le estaré muy agradecido :D

Comment: Si el código de Java te funcionó podrías poner la referencia en la pregunta y así podrían pasarlo a Kotlin.

Comment: Quizás te sirva esto. http://www.alcancelibre.org/staticpages/index.php/imprimiendo-epson-tmu295

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Mañana, o mas bien hoy, probare a ver si funciona una cosa que he encontrado (para java pero lo he convertido en kotlin, no hay una diferencia tan grande salvo un par de cosas que no coincidian), en caso de que funcione lo publico, y en caso que no voy a ver lo que me has enviado ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
val open = byteArrayOf(27, 112, 48, 55, 121)
val printserviceattributeset = HashPrintServiceAttributeSet()
printserviceattributeset.add(PrinterName("", null))
val printservice = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null,printserviceattributeset)
if (printservice.size != 1) {
    println("Printer not found")
}
val pservice = printservice[0]
val job = pservice.createPrintJob()
val flavor = DocFlavor.BYTE_ARRAY.AUTOSENSE
val doc = SimpleDoc(open, flavor, null)
val aset = HashPrintRequestAttributeSet()
try {
    job.print(doc, aset)
    println("Succefully printed")
} catch (ex: PrintException) {
    println(ex.message)
}
```

Disculpad la demora, justo me fui de vacaciones y acabo de volver, aquí os dejo el código el cual funciona. En printerName("") poned entre las comillas el nombre de la impresora de tickets, encontrado en dispositivos e impresoras.